# Perl forkmanager dropping array value

Tags: arrays, multithreading, perl

So I am having an issue with the array @cpuAll losing its value after $pm->finish.. This is just SSHing to a bunch of servers and bringing back some stats which works fine. But the array won't print after the last loop is done. I don't want to write everything to files because I get a 90% performance increase from just loading it into the array.

```
my @cpuAll = ();
my @memAll = ();
$pm->run_on_finish(sub{
        my ($pid,$exit_code,$ident,$exit_signal,$core_dump,$data)=@_;
        push(@data,$data);
});
for(@servers)
{
    next if $_ =~ "10.1.4.52";
    next if $_ =~ "10.1.4.106";
    my $pid = $pm->start and next;
    chomp;
    my @output_cpu  = `/usr/bin/ssh $_ \"/root/scripts/punkbuster.cpu|sed 's/ (//g'|sed 's/)//g'|sed s'/ //g'\"`;
    for(@output_cpu)
    {
        chomp;
        my ($server,$username,$cpu,$process)=(split /:/, $_)[0,1,2,3];
#       push(@cpuAll,"$server\,$username\,$cpu\,$process\,$date\,$time\n");
    }
$pm->finish(0, [$server,$username,$cpu,$process]);
}

print $_ for @data;
print "OK\n";
$pm->wait_all_children;
```

Comment: You add data to `@cpuAll` in the child process, but try to retrieve it from the `@cpuAll` in the parent process. You need to send the data from the child to the parent. See the section in P::FM's docs titled "RETRIEVING DATASTRUCTURES from child processes".

Comment: But I thought since I declared it outside the loop it would stick, your saying since it is an entirely different process it needs to get passed back to utilize in the parent process.

Comment: Yes, changing a variable on one process does not magically affect similarly named variables in other processes. Thank God!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run into similar issues in the past, and I believe you'll find a solution in the documentation on [data structure retrieval](http://search.cpan.org/~szabgab/Parallel-ForkManager-1.05/lib/Parallel/ForkManager.pm#Data_structure_retrieval). You need to pass the data to finish like `$pm->finish(0, \@cpuAll)` and then use a callback in `$pm->run_on_finish` to loop over your array and print whatever you need. The link I provided shows a code example which should be very clear on how to retrieve the data. Let me know if not and I'll add more to my answer.

Comment: Hey, so I did something sort of like that but my run_on_finish was not passing the args properly.

Comment: If it's still not working for you, I would recommend editing your post so we can see the code. Then we can make some informed suggestions.

Comment: I don't really know where to start I am having trouble understanding what the documentation is saying I should do. I don't need to print it but ultimately add all the data from each array generated to a single array.

Comment: Ok I tried an edit, let me know if you can see where I am messing up.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Net::OpenSSH::Parallel](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH%3a%3aParallel)!

```
my $pssh = Net::OpenSSH::Parallel->new;
for my $server (@servers) {
    $pssh->add_host($server);
}
$pssh->push(*, cmd => { stdout_file => "%LABEL%.out" },
            "/root/scripts/punkbuster.cpu|sed 's/ (//g'|sed 's/)//g'|sed s'/ //g'");
$pssh->run;

my @cpuAll;
for my $server (@servers) {
    if (open my $fh, '<', "$server.out") {
        my ($server,$username,$cpu,$process) = split /:/;
        push @cpuAll, join ',', (split /:/)[0..3], $date, $time;
    }
    else {
        warn "unable to retrieve data for $server\n";
    }
}

print "$_\n" for @cpuAll;
```

I would also replace the `sed` substitutions by some local post-processing done in perl.